# Write a Method that Sorts an ArrayList of Numbers

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

From Liang's Intro to Java Programming (10th edition):

Exercise 13.3:
Write the following method that sorts an ArrayList of numbers.

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<Number> list)
```

My code:

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<Number> list) {

    Number temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j).doubleValue() < list.get(i).doubleValue()) {
                temp = list.get(i);
                list.set(i, list.get(j));
                list.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the main method I instantiated an ArrayList of Numbers and some arbitrary values: [7, 1, 3.14, -5, 2, 5.187, 9, 6.6667, 4.1]

My output after using my sort method: [-5, 9, 7, 6.6667, 5.187, 3.14, 2, 1, 4.1] (which is clearly incorrect).

It's pretty late and I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what I did wrong for this problem. If anyone could point out the logical errors that I made it would help save a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<Number> list) {

Number temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
        if (list.get(j).doubleValue() < list.get(i).doubleValue()) {
            temp = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(j));
            list.set(j, temp);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you start the second loop with 0 every time. That means, that you also take the already-ordered elements.

Change your second loop to `for (int j = i+1`..., so you start the inner loop with the unsorted rest of the list (the elements that should really be compared to the one at index `i`).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

you should make the nested loop starts from `i+1` not from `1`

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
    ...
    }
}
```